# What will be the correct output for this question?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int *p, int *q) {
p = q; 
*p = 2; 
} 
int i = 0, j = 1; 
int main() { 
f(&i, &j); 
printf("%d %d n", i, j); 
getchar(); 
return 0; 
}
```

The output here is coming as:
0 2
i.e i=0 and j=2
Hence j is modified but not i...
But according to me p is pointing to i and q is pointing to j.
After, p started pointing to q so i and j both should be modified?

Comment: The answer given is correct. If you can't see why, try stepping through in a debugger.

Comment: This is creepy code LoL

Comment: Why do you think that `i` should be modified?

Comment: The output should be 2, 1. Because p makes reference to q(1) before it gets changed to 2, however q remains the same.

Comment: Please check if more edits for question is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First were sending the addresses of i and j to the function f (f(&i, &j)), this is called "Call by reference", than we got two pointer variable (int *p, int *q) that stores the address of i and j. lets say that the address of i is 2048 and j is 3048 than p=2048 and q=3048 for example.
After that in the function we are storing q into p that means now p stores the address 3048 (address of j), that means were lost the address of i into this function and cannot modify it more, after that were accessing the value into p, address of j in the main function, and by the "value at" operator (*) we changing it to 2.
Now after all that i=0 and j=2. Hope you understood and recommend you to read more about calling by reference. Good luck !

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful.